# How to redirect to another page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two buttons in my code, each trying a different way for redirecting, in one of them i'm trying to use `<a>`, and the other one I'm trying to use route, but none of them seem to work.

Here's my code:

**Component DefineDestino.js:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import CheckOut from "../CheckOut"

export default function DefineDestino(props) {
    const [initialValue, setValue] = useState(0)

    const increment = () => {
        return {
            type:'counter/increment'
        }
    }

    function estadosReducer(state, action) {
        if (state === 'Rio de Janeiro' && action.type === 'counter/increment') {
            setValue(initialValue + 1000)
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Valor: {initialValue}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => estadosReducer(props.data, increment())}>Efetuar Compra</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**App.js:**

```
import Origem from './components/Origem';
import Destino from './components/Destino'
import './styles/App.css';
import React, {useState} from "react"
import EstadosOrigem from './components/Origem';
import EstadosDestino from './components/Destino';
import DefineDestino from './components/DefineDestino';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckOut from './CheckOut';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="mainContent">
          <h1>Escolha um destino.</h1>
            < EstadosOrigem ></EstadosOrigem>
            < EstadosDestino ></EstadosDestino>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/CheckOut" component={CheckOut}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**The page I'm trying to redirect to CheckOut.js:**

```
function CheckOut() {
  return (
    <div className="CheckOut">
      <div className="mainContent">
        <h1>TESTE.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CheckOut;
```

Comment: Use the `Link` component if navigating within your app. Where are you attempting to do any redirection though? Is there a router wrapping the app somewhere to provide a routing context? Can you add all the relevant code se we can see how you are attempting to navigate/redirect and render routes?

Comment: I'm using Link in the App.js file, and tried to use it in the DefineDestino.js, both of them return the address in the browser but the page doesnt change.

Comment: A `Link` alone doesn't do much, can you show the rest of how you are handling routing in your app?

Comment: Actually this is my entire code xd, maybe I'm missing something basic but I'm new at using react, route, etc.

Comment: If there's no router then I'd expect there to be a warning/error about rendering a `Link` outside a `Router`. Either way, then yes, you are missing a router and routes to link to. A router should wrap `App` and provide a routing context, and `App` can then render a `Routes` component wrapping `Route` components. From here you should be able to link to any of the routes you define by path.

Comment: I changed it a bit, added Router in the app, and added Routes with one Routes pathed to my CheckOut.js, but it still only updates the url, the page doesn't chage.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the new code examples?

Comment: `<Route path="/CheckOut" component={CheckOut}></Route>` should be `<Route path="/CheckOut" element={<CheckOut /> } />` in RRDv6.

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: Routing in your code seems to work without issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-react-pnpdu). I had to add a `Link` somewhere to link to the "/CheckOut" path and component, but it's working.

Comment: Do you only have one route?